# Необходим api словарь русского языка

Tags: node.js, api, словарь, поиск-api

Мне необходимо api для node js, чтоб реализовать словарь русского языка с определениями слов. Есть ли такие решения?

Answer (score 0):

Есть Wikidata, можно прочитать здесь [www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Wiktionary](http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Wiktionary)